# GIT not tracking code signed file - how do I force it to update?

Tags: git

I have a binary executable that was included in a main branch a while back.  In a new branch I added the binary but now it was code signed.  Even after merging the branches, the binary in the main branch does not get updated.  So every time I switch branches or fetch the main branch from remote, I have to go and manually get the binary and replace it in the folder.

When I do that, GIT does not show any changes have been made. Even though there is something different about the file.

I am about to just change the binary's file name, and update it in my code.  But was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: `.gitignore`? `git check-ignore -v <thefile.exe>`? `git ls-files -v | grep ^[a-z]` (for the case it was hidden `git update-index --assume-unchanged` or `--skip-worktree`)?

Comment: *After merging branches* in connection with a binary file makes me suspect that a conflict resolution was necessary, and that it wasn't carried out with enough thought.